# iOS UIAlertViewController misplaced returning from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an issue and i don't understand what is happen and how i can solve it. Help is needed. Thanks in advance.

I need to open a UIActivityViewController from a presented viewcontroller on my app. All is right when is presented from a button, image attached.

[image]

But if I go to background and return to the app without close the UIActivityViewController, the strange misplace event takes the scene and the result is the next image:

[image]

The problem is present in all the devices from iOS 10 and above, the code is:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[ @"hello my darling" ]
                                                                                           applicationActivities:nil];
[activityViewController setValue:@"hiiii" forKey:@"subject"];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can't you dismiss it when the app goes to background`

Comment: I think it maybe a bug from Apple. A temporary way to fix it is dismiss UIActivityViewController when app goes to background